# Can not read .env file on React Native with react-native-config package ( Andoid )

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, environment-variables

```
My RN & RNC version:
"react-native-config": "^1.5.0", "react-native": "0.72".
------------------------------------------------
config.ts

import env from "react-native-config";
 
const AppConfig = {
  baseURL: () => {
    console.log(env.API_URL, '-----')
    return
   }
}


.env

ENV=dev
API_URL=https://161.xx.xx.99:3000/api

------------------------------------------------

problem statement is 
env.API_URL is giving undefined , its not picking the .env file
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to the start of the file **android/app/build.gradle** solved my problem:

```
apply from: project(":react-native-config").projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```